# Bad size image in pdf created with itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I have a problem to create a pdf with itextsharp from images in .tiff.
Here is some code :

```
        iTextSharp.text.Document d = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
        PdfWriter pw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(d, new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create));
        d.Open();

        PdfContentByte cb = pw.DirectContent;
        foreach (Image img in imgs)
        {
            d.NewPage();
            d.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height));
            iTextSharp.text.Image timg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(img, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.WHITE);
            timg.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
            cb.AddImage(timg);
            cb.Stroke();
        }
        d.Close();
```

It creates the pdf with two pages but the image on the first page is to big.
The page have the size of the image but it zoom an the bottom left corner of the image.
It does that only with the tiff image, if I take png, it works fine.

Any solution?

Comment: Shouldn't the page size be set before the creation of a new page? If I remember correctly, once a page is created, its size is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of mkl, I found it.
Set the page size (SetPageSize) before the new page command (NewPage)

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
string[] validFileTypes = {"tiff"};
string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
bool isValidFile = false;
if (!isValidFile)
{
Label.Text = "Invalid File. Please upload a File with extension " +
                       string.Join(",", validFileTypes);
}
 else
    {
        string pdfpath = Server.MapPath("pdf");
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfpath + "/Images.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();

        string savePath = Server.MapPath("images\\");
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength != 0)
          {
            string path = savePath + FileUpload1.FileName;
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
            iTextSharp.text.Image tiff= iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(path);
            tiff.ScaleToFit(doc.PageSize.Width, doc.PageSize.Height);
            tiff.SetAbsolutePosition(0,0);
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
            table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(tiff));
            doc.Add(table);
          }
         doc.Close();
      }
```